# Custom role claim in Azure B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to add a custom role attribute (that the user cannot edit) to a B2C custom policy?

I have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-configure-signup-self-asserted-custom) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) resource that show how to add a custom attribute, but it seems they add attributes that the user *can* edit. I wish to have a custom  role or admin attribute that only administrators of my app in Azure can edit inside the Azure B2C interface. I also want the attribute included in the jwt access token that is brought down when users log in.

I am specifically looking to define application roles which can be assigned and edited through the B2C interface and not classic Azure AD. I am under the impression that this can be done through custom policies though I may be mistaken.

Comment: Are you talking about application role? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles

Comment: Yes I’m talking about application roles, but I wish to edit them in the B2C interface as opposed to classic Azure AD.

Comment: Yes, I’m taking about application roles, but I wish to edit them in the B2C interface as opposed to classic Azure AD. I’m using MSAL.js to pull an access token and do not want to log in a second time to classic Azure AD with ADAL.js

Comment: Currently there is no UI for application role. They might release it soon though. When I need to update it, I am doing it through the Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how you plan to assign role to user in your system.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603535/authentication-vs-authorization/53606885#53606885) summarizes three approaches you can potentially take. If you can enhance your question with what kind of roles are you looking for and how do you plan to assign them, you can get better responses.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **No, as of today Azure Active Directory B2C does not support app roles**.
For a more detailed answer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76524016/9199819) for a similar question.