# Azure AD B2C choose Web Applications user has permission to access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm doing a project where we want to centralize all the user's registration in our main website using Azure AD B2C.

In our internal web application we would like to choose which Application the user who have just signed up using B2C he/she could access. For example I could give permission to a user to access an Application A but not to access the Application B, so when he/she sign-in in this application A with B2C, he/she would successfully login, but in application B he/she would not be able.

In the previous project I did with Azure AD B2C, the users who have registered in one of my application could access all my other applications.

But in this case I don't want this, I would like to choose which applications a specific user could access.

Do you know if it is possible to do with Azure AD B2C?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable in Azure AD B2C. You are basically looking for authorization.

Please see below answer
[Authentication vs Authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603535/authentication-vs-authorization/53606885#53606885)

Comment: Thank you very much Abhishek! I will try it out